# Parsing Foursquare API JSON for Leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, leaflet, foursquare

I'm trying to map a JSON on leaflet pulled from Foursquare, but I'm having a difficult time getting it show.

Here is a working script using a [JSON](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/fhrw-4uyv.geojson) from I've taken from NYC Open Data.

```
fetch('complaintdata.json')
          .then(function (response) {
            // Read data as JSON
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(function (data) {
            // Create the Leaflet layer for the data
            var complaintData = L.geoJson(data, {
              pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng, {icon: myIcon});
              },

              onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.on('click', function () {
                  // This function is called whenever a feature on the layer is clicked
                  console.log(layer.feature.properties);

                  // Render the template with all of the properties. Mustache ignores properties
                  // that aren't used in the template, so this is fine.
                  var sidebarContentArea = document.querySelector('.sidebar-content');
                  console.log(sidebarContentArea);
                  sidebarContentArea.innerHTML = Mustache.render(popupTemplate, layer.feature.properties);
                });
              }
            });

            // Add data to the map
            complaintData.addTo(map);

          });
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/g395yw2b) using Google Maps, but I'm having a hard time transferring this over for Leaflet.

Here is the [JSON](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=London&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d14c941735&client_id=BOCHQZ4NF0D2NNFP2HM0INIKPUESPUX3RMRDUX02MPWIYSM2&client_secret=EDNX150PKLS4SMRHWL21Q0KLBAQXYQUQV5RAZI0HZSA1IYGG&v=20161111) I would like to replicate this process for:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to fetch the data and then iterate over the object to build the markers and the popup content.

It seems that your geojson is not compliant with the native L.geoJSON built in method, therefore iterate over the object like dealing with a regular JavaScript object.

Also just to inform you that I used axios to fetch the response.

```
import axios from "axios";

const url =
  "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=London&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d14c941735&client_id=BOCHQZ4NF0D2NNFP2HM0INIKPUESPUX3RMRDUX02MPWIYSM2&client_secret=EDNX150PKLS4SMRHWL21Q0KLBAQXYQUQV5RAZI0HZSA1IYGG&v=20161111";

let geoJson = {};

axios.get(url).then(response => {
  geoJson = { ...response.data.response.venues };
  // console.log(geoJson);
  for (let key in geoJson) {
    let restaurant = geoJson[key];
    // console.log(restaurant);
    const { lat, lng, address } = restaurant.location;
    const { name } = restaurant;
    const popupContent = `<b>Name</b>: ${name} 
                          <br> <b>Address</b>: ${address}
                          <br> <b>Lat</b>: ${lat}, 
                          <br> <b>Lon</b>: ${lng} 
    `;
    L.marker([lat, lng], { icon: customMarker })
      .bindPopup(popupContent)
      .addTo(map);
  }
});
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/182169rr9j)

Comment: It worked! Now I have to figure out how to make the information appear on the sidebar instead as a popup as was previously the case.